# In AngularJS, how to write a reusable ng-pattern?

Tags: angularjs

In several places in my application I have to validate that a field is a valid french phone number.
Like this:

`<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^0[1-6]{1}((([0-9]{2}){4})|((\s[0-9]{2}){4})|((-[0-9]{2}){4}))$/">`

- How could I make the regular expression reused by several input fields in my application without copy/pasting the `regex`?
- How could I localize the `regex`?

Comment: Just define it on the scope and pass it `ng-pattern="pattern"`

Comment: @NewDev In my cases the input fields don't belong to the same controller. Is it possible to use a `filter` or a `service`?

Comment: Then a directive is the better way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Adapt the ngPattern directive :

```
.directive("customPhonePattern", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            var patternExp = "/^0[1-6]{1}((([0-9]{2}){4})|((\s[0-9]{2}){4})|((-[0-9]{2}){4}))$/";

            attr.$observe('customPhonePattern', function (locale) {
                switch (locale) {
                    case "EN":
                        patternExp = "";
                        break;
                    case "DE":
                        patternExp = "";
                        break;
                }

                var regexp = new RegExp(patternExp);

                ctrl.$validate();
            });

            ctrl.$validators.pattern = function (value) {
                return ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || isUndefined(regexp) || regexp.test(value);
            };
        }
    };
})
```

Usage

```
<input type="text" custom-pattern="FR">

<input type="text" custom-pattern="{{ someValue }}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define the constant values like

```
var config = {
  patternLong: "/^0[1-6]{1}((([0-9]{2}){4})|((\s[0-9]{2}){4})|((-[0-9]{2}){4}))$/",
  patternShort: "/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.,-]*$/"
};

angular.module('myApp').value('config', config);
```

Inject this `config` in your controllers in which where ever you need, and use like `config.patternLong`.